# Combine Apache Camel CSV with the splitter pattern

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, splitter

I have a large CSV file that I want to proccess with a rate limit. The [Splitter Pattern](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) provides exactly what I'm looking for except I can't quite figure out how out how to combine it with the [CSV Component](http://camel.apache.org/csv.html).

From the splitter documentation you can handle CSV's like:

```
from("file:inbox")
  .split().tokenize("\n", 1000).streaming()
     .to("activemq:queue:order");
```

But idealy I'd like to make use of the Apache Camel CSV component to handle the mash do something more like:

```
from("file:inbox")
    .unmarshal().csv().split()
    .streaming().parallelProcessing()
    .throttle(requestsPerSecond)
    .bean(new ValidateProcess(), "validate")
    .marshal().csv().to("file:outbox");
```

I know the code above is completely wrong but hopefully it conveys what I'm trying to achieve. Would this be at all feasible?

Comment: What aspect of the csv() data-format do you wish to leverage? For instance, do you want to use its ability to unmarshal each line as a Map or would you prefer lists? The marshaling assumes Map or List<Map> as its input.

Comment: I want to unmarshal each line to `List<List<String>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason I couldn't figure this out earlier, I think I was having issue with my classpath not picking up the dependency on `org.apache.camel:camel-csv`. Once I sorted that out everything was fine.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
final CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat(";");
csv.setLazyLoad(true);
csv.setSkipFirstLine(true);

from(in).unmarshal(csv).split(body()).streaming().parallelProcessing()
                    .bean(validator, "validateNumber")
                    .filter(header(ValidateProcess.Valid).isEqualTo(true))
                    .throttle(tps).bean(validator, "validate")
                    .marshal().csv()
                    .to(out).log("done.").end();
```

Basicaly I wanted to stream process a `CSV` containing numbers against an `API` which is rate limited at 50 TPS and output the result to  csv file.

Comment: Doesn't that pull in the entire file though (as a List<List<String>> and only apply streaming+parallelProcessing over that complete List of Lists? Or, is that your intent? Also, before you marshal using csv, are you converting to a Map, since that's what csv expects?